# Using C# bluetooth API on windows mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I want to work with bluetooth in a C# application. I do not want to use third party components. I want to talk with official Microsoft API in direct.

What i want to do is just power on/off bluetooth, scan for available devices, pairing/unpairing devices.

I have read some threads talking about a dll called bthutil.dll but i do not have this dll on my device. It is a psion workabout.

Why this dll is not on my device ? Where can i download this dll (official package) ?

Is there some alternatives to bthutil.dll, without having to install a third party component ?

The control panel contains official software that are able to configure, so i suppose my devices already contains official API somewhere...

Thanks

Comment: I would go with the 32feet libs and tools. Possibly bthutil.dll is just hidden (file explorer: show all files) as it may be system and XIP.

Comment: I have search for hidden files. do you know on which layer works 32feet lib ?

Comment: AFAIR 32feet supports MS and Widcom BT stack on mobile devices. If the psion does not use one of these you need to use there Bluetooth SDK (they must provide this SDK).

Answer (score 0):

BthUtil.dll is part of Windows CE/Mobile, but Psion would have to explicitly include the dll in the OS image (by setting the appropriate [SYSGEN variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495917.aspx) at build time).

My hunch is that either Psion decided to omit BthUtil.dll, perhaps to save space, or that the Psion devices are using a proprietary Bluetooth stack. In the latter case your best bet would be to check if an SDK is available from Psion, and if so, examine the documentation and/or sample code to determine how to manage the Bluetooth features.

Comment: Exact, there is a specific API provided by psion, but this API is not able to scan for peripheral. I have to know the MAC address of the device i want to pair...

Comment: Sounds like you will be limited to Psion's API's then, possibly reverse engineering the calls made from the control panel applets or other applications. Note that Psion might have adapted the standard control panel applets to their own stack, so the existence of said applets and ability to manage the Bluetooth features does not necessarily mean they are using standard CE/Mobile functions under the hood